# How should I handle a potentially large number of edits in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using .NET 4.5.1 with EF 6.0.2 and db-first.

The use case is something like this:

1. Roughly 50k entities are loaded
2. A set of these entities are displayed for the user, others are required for displaying the items correctly
3. The user may perform heavy actions on the entities, meaning the user chooses to perform one action which cascades to actually affect potentially hundreds of entities.
4. The changes are saved back to database.

The question, then, is what is the best way to handle this? So far I've come up with 2 different solutions, but don't really like either:

1. Create a DbContext at step 1. Keep it around during the whole process, then finally save changes. The reason I don't necessarily like this, is that the process might take hours, and as far as I know, DbContexts should not be preserved for this long.
2. Create a DbContext at step 1. Discard it right after. At step 4, create a new DbContext, attach the modified entities to it and save changes. The big problem I see with this approach is how do I figure out which entities have actually be changed? Do I need to build a ChangeTracker of my own to be able to do this?

So is there a better alternative for handling this, or should I use one of the solutions above (perhaps with some changes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with option number 1 - use a DbContext for the entire process.

The problem I have is with the assertion that `the process might take hours`. I don't think this is something you want to do. Imagine what happens when your user has been editing the data for 3 hours, and then face a power blackout before clicking the final save. You'll have users running after you with pitchforks.

You're also facing a lot of concurrency issues - what if two users perform the same lengthy process at once? Handling collisions after a few hours of work is going to be a problem, especially if you tell users changes they've made hours ago can't be saved. Pitchforks again.

So, I think you should go with number 3 - save incremental changes of the editing process, so the user's work isn't lost if something bad happens, and so that you can handle collisions if two users are updating the data at the same time.

You would probably want to keep the incremental changes in a separate place, not your main tables, because the business change hasn't been finalized yet.

Comment: liked `You'll have users running after you with pitchforks.`

Answer (score 1):

> and as far as I know, DbContexts should not be preserved for this long.

Häh?

There is nothing in a db context about not preserving it. You may get problems with other people having already edited the item, but that is an inherent architectura problem - generally it isn ot adviced to use optimistic AND pessimistic locking in a "multi hour edit marathon".

The only sensible approach if you have editing over hours is using your own change tracker and using proper logic when changes collode - and / or use a logical locking mechanism (flag in the database).